# Integrating Symfony2 and Redis

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to integrate Redis with my Symfony API, I found this bundle : [RedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

I installed it and configured so that I can cache Doctrine like so config.yml:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

        metadata_cache_driver: redis
        # enable query caching
        query_cache_driver: redis

snc_redis:
# configure predis as client
clients:
    default:
        type: predis
        alias: default
        dsn: redis://localhost
    doctrine:
        type: predis
        alias: doctrine
        dsn: redis://localhost
# configure doctrine caching
doctrine:
    metadata_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: default
        document_manager: default
    result_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: [default]
    query_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: default
```

In my FetchBookRepository I am trying to use RedisCache there:

```
<?php

namespace BooksApi\BookBundle\Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;

use Snc\RedisBundle\Doctrine\Cache\RedisCache;
use Predis\Client;

class FetchBookRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    public $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ){
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return null|object
     * @throws QueryException
     */
    public function fetchBook($id)
    {

        $predis = new RedisCache();
        $predis->setRedis(new Client);
        $cache_lifetime= 3600;

        try {
            $book = $this->em->getRepository('BooksApiBookBundle:BooksEntity')
                ->find($id);

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $this->em->close();
            throw new QueryException('003', 502);
        }

        return $book;
    }
}
```

I called the RedisCahce and Client classes but how do I now use it with my query..? I cant really find much on Google in regards to Symfony & Redis.

UPDATE:

When I use redis-cli and type in MONITOR i get this output:

```
1454337749.112055 [0 127.0.0.1:60435] "GET" "[BooksApi\\BookBundle\\Entity\\BooksEntity$CLASSMETADATA][1]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Redis config looks OK.
You are using Redis to cache Meatada (Doctrine collected about Entities mappings, etc) and Query (DQL to SQL).

To use Redis as Cache for Results you must write custom Query and define that it is cacheable. Please follow the Doctrine manual http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache and this GitHub issue https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/issues/77

Comment: More, you can monitor what is going on in Redis by connecting to Redis server with "redis-cli" and typing "MONITOR" command. It will list all activity on Redis server on all databases. You can use it on development environment, but should never use on production.

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestions I will look into ResultCaching, If you look at my edited question what does eacly means the CLI output I get..? thx

Comment: It is a request for [Metadata](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html) cache for BooksApi\BookBundle\Entity\BooksEntity located in Database #0 under key "[BooksApi\\BookBundle\\Entity\\BooksEntity$CLASSMETADATA][1]"

Comment: I followed your suggestions and managed to get it working than you. Few other question arisen but will take these outside this thread.